# How to get a list of textboxes where I can access their properties

Tags: vb.net

I need to get a list of textboxes, and then find a label with a matching name + the prefix "lb_", then call the function on it. I havn't found anyone with this problem on here. For somereason, it reads the name of the label but the name of the textbox comes out to the number it came up in the list.

It also fails to loop through each textbox in the list of Textboxes, only through the first item, but it does loop through every label. I've confirmed that the statement "Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)" returns a list of the appropriate length.

```
For Each t In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    Dim l = DirectCast(Controls("lb_" & t.Name), Label)
    If Not l Is Nothing Then
        SetControlProps_EnLo_KP(t, l)
    End If
Next
```

All of the code is located on the code for the form.

**EDIT:** So what I really want to know is possible solutions/causes to txtbox.Name returning "1" instead of "txtbox", even if placed outside of the for each loop.

SOLUTION: there was a loop setting all textbox names to vbNull. I guess by default, if a name is set to null, it becomes "1", no matter which textbox was referenced, the name property was "1"

Comment: If any of the labels or textboxes are contained within a panel, they won't appear in the `Controls` collection.

Comment: If you were going to use nested loops like that (you don't need to, as per my answer below) then you should have an `Exit For` inside the `If` block because there's no point searching for a match if you have already found one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I changed my code to match yours, but it didn't fix my problem. Side note, there are some textboxes in a panel, I will loop through those separately when the loop works.

Comment: when you say for the form, do you mean in the form_load? Because if that's the case you are probably getting an exception that isn't stopping execution of the form being shown. Place this code inside the form_shown to ensure that all controls on it have been loaded before this code runs.

Comment: no, not in the form load, in the form class inside a function that gets called by a click event.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `vbNull` for anything. The `vbNull` constant contains the value `VariantType.Null`. `VariantType` is an `Enum` so its fields all have numeric values and the numeric value of the `Null` field is 1.  That's why the `Name` of every `TextBox` was being set to "1". DO NOT use `vbNull` to represent no value.  If you want to value, use `Nothing`.  That said, why you would want to clear the `Name` properties of you controls is a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each t In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    Dim l = DirectCast(Controls("lb_" & t.Name), Label)
```

If there might not be a match, test `l` for `Nothing` before using.

If some `TextBoxes` are on a different parent, you can do this:

```
For Each t In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Concat(otherParentControl.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)())
```

Comment: Controls.OfType(Of TextBox) isn't returning an accurate list of the textboxes on the form and the .Name property is "1" even though there is no textbox with that name on the form. The .Text property however, does reflect what is in the textboxes.

Comment: If the `Name` property of the `TextBox` contains "1" then there is a `TextBox` on the form with that name because that's it.  The `Name` property IS the name. You probably mean that there is no field in the class with that name but the field is not the `TextBox`. When you add a `TextBox` to the form in the designer, the name of the field that refers to it and the `Name` property value will be the same but you can change the value of the `Name` property and I can only assume that that is what you have done. The only other explanation seems to be something corrupted somewhere.

Comment: I just tested it (outside of the loop) with:             MessageBox.Show(txt_FI_Name.Name) and it returns "1"

Comment: It works, however for getting all controls I prefer to use my `GetControls` method. And also to find a control I prefer `Controls.Find("name", true)` to search between all controls. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to return an `IEnumerable(Of Control)` containing all descendant controls of the form:

```
Public Iterator Function GetControls(C As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    For Each Child As Control In C.Controls
        Yield Child
        For Each GrandChild In GetControls(Child)
            Yield GrandChild
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

Then if you just want textboxes, use `OfType(Of TextBox)`:

```
dim list = GetControls(Me).OfType(Of TextBox)
```

Above list contains all text box controls of a form regardless of the parent.

Also to find a label control by name:

```
dim label = Me.Controls.Find("the name", True).OfType(Of Label).FirstOrDefault()
```