# VB How To Select All Controls Of Type And Set Text To Nothing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

im coding a sequence guesser game and id like to program it so whenever you enter a number wrong it resets all the labels how would i universally select the label type and make the text = `Nothing`
i tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx) but it didnt work

Thanks

```
  Imports System.Media
Public Class comboForm

    Dim score As Integer = 0
    Dim winsound As New SoundPlayer(My.Resources.winsound_wav)



    ' 1 7 8 8 4 7 1 5 5



    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        If score = 0 Then
            score += 1
            lblStage1.Text = "1"
        ElseIf score = 7 Then
            score += 1
            lblStage7.Text = "7"
        Else
            score = 0
            For Each lbl In tlpMain.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
                lbl.Text = Nothing
            Next


        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't post a link to code from somewhere else that you tried to make use of.  Show us the actual code that you used, posted directly in your question and formatted properly for readability.

Comment: By the way, that code is specifically for an ASP.NET Web Forms application, although the WinForms equivalent is not much different.  Are you creating a Web Forms application?  If so then you should add appropriate tags so people know that. If it's not then you should still add appropriate tags.  VB.NET is not enough if your question relates to a specific technology. I've assumed Windows Forms because that's what most people start with but you should add the appropriate tag in that case too. Do all you can to help us help you. If we post a solution that's not relevant it wastes everyone's time.

Comment: Its vb.net forms application

Comment: There's no such thing as a "vb.net forms" application.  VB.NET is a language.  Windows Forms and Web Forms are two different technologies, one for creating Windows apps and one for creating web apps.  They have a lot of similarities but they also have differences.  When you post a question, add ALL the relevant tags.  If you're talking about controls then what technology those controls are part of is always relevant, so add the appropriate tag.

Comment: well its a windows form then

Comment: So you appear to have used the code I suggested.  Did it work?  I probably ought to point out, given that you're unlikely to do the research that would let you discover it for yourself, that using `Me.Controls` is only going to access controls that are added directly to the form.  If they were added to another container, e.g. a `Panel`, then you need to use the `Controls` collection of that container.  If you want to access controls in different containers then it's a bit more complex because there's no single collection that contains them all. Is that your scenario?

Comment: they're in a table layout panel and no it didnt work because i just have a loop with no code for it to execute

Comment: and just to be clear im watching something on for loops but it just doesnt make sense a while loop makes so much more sense

Comment: "they're in a table layout panel". In that case, as I just said, you need to use the `Controls` collection of the `TableLayoutPanel` rather than the form. "it didnt work because i just have a loop with no code for it to execute". Except that what you posted does have code to execute and it didn't work for a very different reason."im watching something on for loops". Again, this is a `For Each` loop, NOT a `For` loop.

Comment: @jmcilhinney theres the updated code, still doesnt work

Comment: Argh! It would have worked if you had just done what I said! I told you to use the `Controls` collection of the TLP, which you did, BUT you also changed the code inside the loop for some unfathomable reason.  Now you're clearing the `Text` of the form instead of the `Label`.  Inside the loop `lbl` IS the `Label`.  Maybe you should have spent some time learning about `For Each` loops rather than `For` loops.

Comment: updated code, if thats what u meant that also doesnt  work @jmcilhinney

Comment: That is what I meant and, in fact, that code works perfectly.  I just tested it myself. I created a new project, added a `TableLayoutPanel`, added six `Labels` to that, added a `Button` to the form, created a `Click` event handler for the `Button` and then copied the loop from your code.  I ran the project, clicked the `Button` and all the `Labels` were cleared.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so why tf doesnt mine work

Comment: Maybe that code doesn't even get executed.  Have you actually debugged it?  Probably not.  Maybe do that, i.e. set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line.  Of course, if the `Labels` aren't even on that TLP then of course using the `Controls` collection of the TLP doesn't work. Basically, you have all you need to address the problem you posted about.  If you have another problem, I'm not going to be part of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51104285/9998803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each lbl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    '...
Next
```

The `OfType` method is basically a filter by type on a list.  That code is pretty much the equivalent of this:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
        Dim lbl = DirectCast(ctrl, Label)

        '...
    End If
Next
```

or this:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Dim lbl = TryCast(ctrl, Label)

    If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Obviously this code will only access `Labels` directly on the form, because it uses the form's `Controls` collection.  Use the `Controls` collection of the appropriate container, e.g. a `Panel` to access controls in that container.

Comment: in the ' ... part would i just put text = nothing?

Comment: You would put whatever code you need to achieve your aim. The title of your question is specifically about selecting all controls of a specific type.  What you do with each of those controls is irrelevant to how you do that.  There's no reason for you to ask about something as basic as clearing the text of a `Label`.

Comment: theres nine labels if i did it manually id have to do lblname.text = nothing how do i do that to all of them was kinda the question

Comment: You need to use your head. That's a `For Each` loop I posted there.  Inside the loop there is only one `Label`.  You just said yourself that you already know how to do what you need for one `Label`.  If that's a serious question, it's only because you haven't done what you should have already and learned the basics, including how loops work.

Comment: Ive tried i just dont understand for loops while loops i understand but for loops befuddle me it doesnt make sense to me the whole point of the post was to get help and you clearly have the knowledge so why dont you give me the answer

Comment: Because that's not what this site is for.  We're here to help with the stuff you can't work out on your own, not to teach you the basics of programming.  If you don't understand loops then go and do some more research or get a book or post somewhere that is intended for that stuff. This site has a purpose and I'm more than happy to help you or anyone else with that intended purpose.  I'm not here as a substitute for you doing your own work though.

Comment: im not asking you to do my work im asking you how to apply a method to a universal selection

Comment: my understanding of a for loop is that it runs to check a conditional in this case it would be if theres a label with the starter text lbl i assume unless vb understands lbl and if the conditional is met it runs code but everyone tells me thats wrong

Comment: Then your understanding is very, VERY flawed and you need to go and spend some time learning how they work.  Loops have nothing to do with conditions but rather repetition.  This is a `For Each` loop too, which is different to a `For` loop.

Comment: so ur not gonna let me move on and tell the little bit of code you know but wont tell me to get this done or are you gonna be mysterious and tell me to learn the basics of programming

Comment: I'm not being mysterious at all. I'm telling you straight up that I'm not here to teach you the basics of programming and neither is this site. I'm not stopping you moving on. If making the effort to learn the basics is too much for you, that's on you. I'm done here. You can wait for someone else who doesn't mind spoon-feeding if you want but that's not me. I expect people to learn the basics for themselves and those who can't or won't are not my concern.

Comment: i now have an understanding of a for loop its just a rearranged while loop, the start condition the condition to check and the increment so its just a condensed while loop

Comment: So you say that now you have an understanding of `For` loops. and it's less than an hour since you posted your question.  Apparently it's not so impossible to learn the basics after all.  Googling is useless if you don't look for the right things or don't use the information you find. You spent all this time telling me how you couldn't understand loops and now you say that you understand `For` loops, so all that time was wasted claiming something that was untrue. I've seen it all before many times. What seems to hard is not; it just takes a bit of time and effort.

Comment: my understanding had been warped by everyone telling me it was wrong so in the end i gave up i never used one i never had a solution where one wouldve been helpful because at that point i didnt know their practical implication anymore im easily knocked down and i give up easily which is why i started coding in the first place its mass failure and trial and error so in the end i appreciate your help but my understanding now is a for each loop runs for everything matching a data type specified and then runs it through the logic gate process as normal

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney also realised that the labels arent in the tlp but still the code doesnt work with the laoyout panel selector or me selector

Comment: @jmcilhinney ive just realised something and im genuinely sorry that ive wasted your time this was set to trigger if a value wasnt one or seven but the button it was attached too couldnt make that value rise past one so sorry thank you for teaching me this however now i can finally go to bed in the end i guess i understood i was just being a blind twatbag

Comment: All's well that ends well.