# Looping through all NumericUpDown to check the value

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to Looping through all NumericUpDown and check the value?

```
For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
    Dim numControls As NumericUpDown = TryCast(control, NumericUpDown)
    If numControls.Value > 14 Then
        MsgBox("ok")
    End If
Next
```

the one i tried but didnt work

Comment: Use `For Each numControl in Me.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)()`. Also, make sure that all of those controls are placed directly on the form, and not on another container (e.g., Panel, GroupBox, etc.). Otherwise, you need to use `theContainer.Controls` instead of `Me.Controls`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB How To Select All Controls Of Type And Set Text To Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716951/vb-how-to-select-all-controls-of-type-and-set-text-to-nothing)

Comment: Do not name singular object variables in the plural

Comment: (If you're strict about naming single objects as singular and collections/arrays/lists as plural it makes the code much less confusing. Compare `For Each person In people` versus calling your array "person" means you write `For Each people In person`). You'll note that Microsoft are generally very good at following this rule and it leaves you with code that reads like a book - `For Each control ... In Controls` - note that in more recent versions of VB you can also skip the `As ...` on the ForEach dec if the type can be inferred from the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done makes some sense but it has a glaring flaw. The whole point of `TryCast` is that it returns `Nothing` if the cast fails rather than throwing an exception. You then go ahead and use that result as though it's not `Nothing` and cause a `NullReferencxeException` anyway. If you are using `TryCast` then you ALWAYS need to be testing the result for `Nothing`. If you don't need to do that because you know the result will not be `Nothing` then you shouldn't be using `TryCast` in the first place.

```vb
Dim numControls = TryCast(control, NumericUpDown)

If numControls IsNot Nothing AndAlso numControls.Value > 14 Then
```

That said, you can cast and filter in one go, so there's no need for that:

```vb
For Each numControls In Me.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)
    If numControls.Value > 14 Then
```

The example code also assumes that the controls have been added to the form directly. If they have been added to some other container, e.g. a `Panel`, then you need to use the `Controls` collection of that container rather than the form.

Comment: Do not name singular object variables in the plural

Comment: @CaiusJard, that's good advice and all but I just copied the code from the question. If you have an issue with what the OP is doing that is unrelated to the issue then probably comment on the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not acceptable to have less than 15 in any of your NumericUpDowns, then set their Minimum property to 15, obviating this check entirely

If for some reason you still need to do it I'd recommend something like

```
If Me.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown).Any(Function(nud) nud.Value < 15)) Then ...
```

This way you do something once if any of them are less than 15.

Try and avoid using MessageBoxes if you can; they're very disruptive to user flow through a UI. Certainly having 10 NUD on a form and if they're all over 14 showing 10 "ok" messageboxes in a row will be incredibly annoying for the user